# Image is only shown when OnCreate Activity has finished

Tags: android, refresh, imageview

I have a simple program that displays an image. I load the image in the onCreate method but when I attach the debugger I notice that the image is only shown on the screen when the onCreate method has finished. Unfortunately I want to reload the image continuously so I added a loop. Now no image is shown on the screen (because onCreate doesn't finish). I've already tried to set the visibility of the imageview to visible but that didn't change anything. Is there a set* that I have to call or is it a bad idea to loop in the onCreate Method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately I want to reload the image continuously so I added a loop.
>   Now no image is shown on the screen
>   (because onCreate doesn't finish).

Executing that loop in the UI thread is a really really bad idea.  Try something like this:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Thanks but I tried this too. I grabbed the imageview by 

    Drawable drawable = MyLoader.getDrawable();
    ImageView imgView = MyLoader.getImgView();

and 
        drawable = LoadImage(inputUrl);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

but moving this code outside of onCreate doesn't update the display. Or maybe it does but it isn't shown?

Comment: Could you post some more code so that we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Of course: http://pastebin.com/h6EPMJxT

I can load an image from an external source and display it correctly on the android phone if I comment out everything after Checkpoint 1. If I add code like the timer task no update of the image view happens. The program keeps running, data is also fetched but the image stays the same. The new images are not shown ...  thanks a lot for your advises

Comment: So the images you are downloading are always coming from the same URL?  You might need to add some sort of parameter to the URL to keep the response from being cached (which could cause the same image to be displayed over and over).

Comment: Yes, it's a webcam. I tried to add ?i=x (x=1,...) but it remains the same image.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to create a handler. The Timer thread couldn't update the imageview. Unfortunately no error was thrown ...